# log tcp contakting connection with nftables

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, tcp

I Want to log  TCP contracting Connexion using nftables(iptables)
  I tried to write tcp flags in Rule, but when I acces to webpage of destination IP address I get just this Info in my logfile :

Result of logFile :

`DPT=80 SEQ=3355573072 ACK=0 WINDOW=8192 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0`

RULE :

`add rule filter mychain ip saddr 1.1.1.2 ip daddr . tcp  dport tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg) == (fin|psh|urg)  accept`.

Comment: thanks for your Ansewr  . I am using NFLOG in Ulogd. Can we see the flags TCP in Forward Chain ? wish is better

Comment: with contrack-based https://home.regit.org/2014/02/logging-connection-tracking-event-with-ulogd/   we dont see also tcp flags